# ¿Como validar el incremento de dias con FULL CALENDAR?

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

Con la documentación de `fullcalendar` he tomado la siguiente función:

```
   eventResize: function(event, delta, revertFunc)
                    {
                        var id =  event.id;
                        var fi = event.start.format();
                        var ff = event.end.format();  
                        var titulo = event.title;                           
                    }
```

Esta función me sirve para extender la fecha o evento hasta la fecha deseada, el problema es que no encuentro la forma de validar, **si la fecha final es mayor a 7 dias desde la fecha inicial que aparezca un error**.

He intentado:

```
    if(ff > 7)
    {
     alert("No puede sobre pasar los 7  dias");
    }
y esto
var fecha_de_validacion = moment.format('YYYY-MM-DD' + (parseInt(7)));
```

pero no funciona

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No uses el evento como referencia. Usa `delta`. Como dice la [documentación](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/utilities/Duration/), este es un elemento de duración que indica cuanto se ha estirado el evento.

Si lo [transformamos a días](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/days/), puedes usar:

```
if(delta.asDays() > 7){
    alert("No puede sobrepasar los 7  días");
}
```